# Property of $f(x, y)= z$ for all permutations of $x, y, z$

Tags: terminology

What property would you say a function $f(x, y)= z$ has if it is true for all permutations of values $x, y, z$?

Comment: Are $x, y, z$ fixed numbers?

Comment: Yes. An example function would be $f(x,y) = 1-x-y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f\colon A\to A$ be a function. Assume that for all $x,y,z$ with $f(x,y)=z$, we also have $f(y,x)=z$, $f(x,z)=f(z,x)=y$ and $f(y,z)=f(z,y)=x$.

Equivalently, $f$ is **symmetric**, i.e., $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ for all $x,y\in A$, and additionally $f(x,f(x,y))=y$ for all $x,y\in A$, i.e., for every fixed $a\in A$, $f(a,\cdot)$ is **involutory**.

Comment: Thanks. Would you happen to know of any examples of two variable functions which are both symmetric and involutory?